# Right way to launch thousands of Backgroundworkers?

Tags: c#

I wrote a program that scans around 10.000 computer in the network for uptime, active user, idletime and ping.
The program performs great. Mostly checking all computers in around 3 minutes.
But lately, the program keeps freezing. It has done all the tasks, but it will not exit.
I launch all the BackGroundWorkers like this:

```
foreach (DataRow computer in computerTable.Rows)
                {
                    //Added check to see if computer is in inputlist for inputfilemode
                    if (!inputFileMode || (inputFileMode && computerList.Contains(computer["ComputerName"].ToString())))
                    {
                        BackgroundWorker bw = new BackgroundWorker();
                        //Determine background jobs
                        bw.DoWork += bw_DoWork;
                        bw.RunWorkerCompleted += bw_RunWorkerCompleted;

                        bw.RunWorkerAsync(computer); //Start background worker
                        numberOfWorkers++;
                    }
                }


                int lastNr = 0;
                int skipHangingJobsCounter = 0;
                do
                {
                    lastNr = numberOfWorkers;
                    Thread.Sleep(1000);

                    Console.WriteLine("Tijd: " + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd-HH:mm:ss") + " #Jobs queued: " + numberOfWorkers.ToString() + " Jobs/sec: " + (lastNr - numberOfWorkers).ToString() + " -ForcedShutdowns: " + forcedReboots.ToString() + " -MSIEXEC Exceptions: " + machinesMSI.ToString()); //Report progress
                    if (lastNr - numberOfWorkers == 0)
                    {
                        skipHangingJobsCounter++;
                        if (skipHangingJobsCounter > 30) break; //Safety breakout if a worker hangs
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        skipHangingJobsCounter = 0;
                    }

                    //Timing break
                    double minutesRunning = DateTime.Now.Subtract(startOfJob).TotalMinutes;
                    if (minutesRunning > 13)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Job is running for 14 minutes. Job will be cancelled. Jobs queued remaining: " + numberOfWorkers.ToString());
                        break;
                    }

                } while (numberOfWorkers > 0); //Wait till all jobs are finished
```

I am wondering: is this the most effective way to launch and track all the background jobs? Is het better to create a List array?
I think that will take a lot of memory, or not?

In the do_work section I have a lot of WMI queries, for uptime, etc. Can it be that my program will not exit because of hanging WMI queries? Anyone else experimented with this?

SO bascially I have 2 questions:

1- Am I launching the backgroundworkers in a efficient/correct way?

2- Is het possible that WMI calls in the threads cause the program to fail to exit?

UPDATE:

I re-wrote the code as follows. It's about 3 times faster now. I still use 1 background worker, but only, so I can give feedback on the main thread. The way it is supposed to work I think :)

Main Thread:

```
                    BackgroundWorker bw = new BackgroundWorker();
                bw.DoWork += bw_DoWork;
                bw.RunWorkerCompleted +=bw_RunWorkerCompleted;
                bw.RunWorkerAsync();

                int lastNr = numberOfWorkers;
                do
                {
                    lastNr = numberOfWorkers;
                    Thread.Sleep(1000); //Give feedback every second

                    Console.WriteLine("Tijd: " + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd-HH:mm:ss") + " #Jobs queued: " + numberOfWorkers.ToString() + " Jobs/sec: " + (lastNr - numberOfWorkers).ToString() + " -ForcedShutdowns: " + forcedReboots.ToString() + " -MSIEXEC Exceptions: " + machinesMSI.ToString()); //Report progress

                    //Timing break
                    double minutesRunning = DateTime.Now.Subtract(startOfJob).TotalMinutes;
                    if (numberOfWorkers < 3)
                    {
                        //We are waiting for 3 last workers. Give feedback which 3 thse are
                        foreach (Task t in taskArray)
                        {
                            if (t.Status == TaskStatus.Running)
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine("Waiting for " + taskList[t.Id]);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    if (minutesRunning > 13)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Job is running for 14 minutes. Job will be cancelled. Jobs queued remaining: " + numberOfWorkers.ToString());
                        break;
                    }

                } while (!jobDone); //Wait till all jobs are finished
```

Background Work

```
        static void bw_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        JobLauncher();
    }

    static void JobLauncher()
    {


        foreach (DataRow computer in computerTable.Rows)
        {
            //Added check to see if computer is in inputlist for inputfilemode
            if (!inputFileMode || (inputFileMode && computerList.Contains(computer["ComputerName"].ToString())))
            {
                Task t = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => CheckComputer(computer));
                taskList.Add(t.Id, computer["ComputerName"].ToString());
                taskArray.Add(t);

                numberOfWorkers++;
            }
        }

        Task.WaitAll(taskArray.ToArray());
    }
```

Comment: it is not a good idea to use async method inside a for loop

Comment: and why you need to start backgroundworker for each computer ???

Comment: What about having a few workers that process your computerTable.Rows? Your "computerTable.Rows" could be a queue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of all this, you could better use a predefined method that checks if all tasks have ended. Your code if very error prone and likely to shut the entire application down. And why start 1 thread for every computer? 10.000 threads? It seems overkill to me.

My suggestion would be to use tasks instead of background workers. If you have network I/O, you can most likely `await` that, increasing overall performance. Just `Task.WhenAll` them, and you will notice when they are ready.

Another way is to use the Parrallel library. You can `Parrallel.Foreach` the list of computers, trottle them to a max of 16 or so, and the .NET framework will do all the looping and checking for you.

Comment: The code itself is perfectly stable and doing what it mus do. Here's some output on the console. It's not starting 10.000 threads. It's queuing them as far as I know. And then handling according to processing power:   Number of computer found:9596
Tijd: 20160104-23:00:02 #Jobs queued: 9591 Jobs/sec: 4 -ForcedShutdowns: 0 -MSIEXEC Exceptions: 0
Tijd: 20160104-23:00:03 #Jobs queued: 9589 Jobs/sec: 2 -ForcedShutdowns: 0 -MSIEXEC Exceptions: 0
Tijd: 20160104-23:00:04 #Jobs queued: 9584 Jobs/sec: 5 -

Comment: Can you elaborate on this? Doesnt the background worker do this for me? I mean. What's the difference in processing between the three options?

Comment: And using Tasks does? So I just replace the  start of a BackGroundWorker with the start of a Tasl? Can you give me a sample for this many background threads/jobs?. Right now It finishes the job in about 3 minutes. Not bad I think. You think with Task's it will be faster?

Comment: Thanks. I think I will use the Task option in an array.